# only calling function on outside click not works as expected

Tags: angular, angular-directive

In my angular directive, there is popup shows on click of host element. when the popup open state, if the user click on outside anywhere, I required to close the popup. for that i trying with following code. but not works.  `this.removeComponent();` method always calling.

```
@HostListener("window:mouseup", ["$event"]) clickedOut(event) {
if (event.target.nativeElement === this.hostElement) {
  //when click on host element do nothing!
  return;
}
//when click outside otherthan this.hostElement remove the componenet
this.removeComponent();
}
```

Any one please help me to handle this scenario?

[image: Not able to click on menu]

Comment: Can you reproduce the scenario on stackbiz or somewhere, where we can edit the code since here it's only the HostListener has posted

Comment: @Sanira - here is the demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fp4hfm?file=src/app/directive/my-directive.ts click on `Start editing to see some magic happen :)` and click outside to remove the style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be

```
  @HostListener('window:mouseup', ['$event']) clickedOut(event) {

    //you looking for "event.target" into "this.element.nativeElement"

    if (!this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      console.log("outside")
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("inside")
 
    }
  }
```

NOTE: Use `event.stopPropagation();` in the HostListener (click) if you don't want that is propagate the click on the element

```
   @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(event) {
    ....
    event.stopPropagation(); //<---this line
  }
```

Or remove it completly and only use the hostListener about window:mouseup

the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ztl2u9?file=src/app/directive/my-directive.ts) (only show in console click-outside and click inside)

**Update** with this aproach, you get so many "click-outside" as elements with the directive you has

There're no problem if our dfirective is to show a pop-up or similar because we generally have no many elements at time. But imagine our directive is only to put a border -as the example-. We shoul take another aproach. First we can use HostBinding, so our directive can mannage only to create a border. See that we inject the elementRef as "public"

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[showpop]'
})
export class ShowPopDirective {
  border: boolean=false;
  constructor( public elementRef: ElementRef ) {}

  @HostBinding('style.border') get _(){return this.border?'1px solid red':null}
  
}
```

And we can control from out component the outside

```
  @ViewChildren(ShowPopDirective) items:QueryList<ShowPopDirective>
  @HostListener('window:mouseup', ['$event']) clickedOut(event) {
    this.items.forEach(x=>{
      x.border=!x.border && x.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)
    })
  }
```

The new [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wasgwt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: can you update here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fp4hfm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirective%2Fmy-directive.ts

Comment: just update the answer with your forked stackblitz

Comment: Need a small suggession, when I implement this code, I am getting 13 time consoled onclick, what is the issue? I am using angular8, for you case in stackblitz it consoles only one time

Comment: You'll get so many "click-outside" as elements with the directive you have. Try re-start the app (or refresh the navigator). BTW I update the answer to control a series of directive using ViewChildren -but I think that this is **not** your case-. Another suggestion is use rxjs operator `fromEvent`-dont' forget unsubscribe- instead HostListener, but I think that hostListener should be correct

Comment: thanks for your answers. though I finding an issue, updated the screen shot. when i click on the radio button the popup get closes. no function triggers. it consider that I am clicking on outside. I tried with adding propagation but no luck. any help please?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem, the problem had occured coz you were comparing an element with an array of element which will always be false thus giving you the error.

```
@HostListener("window:mouseup", ["$event"]) clickedOut(event) {
    if (this.hostElement.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      //when click on host element do nothing!
      return;
    }
    else{
    this.removeComponent();
    }
    //when click outside other than this.hostElement remove the component
    }
```

Comment: getting an error as: `Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined`

Comment: Edited the answer, please Check